# Display the content inside a division from another page after submitting a form in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect

I am a product engineer and new to coding,
but now I am making a portfolio website from a template. I have successfully made a form and transferred the submitted contents to the Google Sheet, but I want to do more.
I want to embed the "thank you page" `thankyou.html` inside the existing division `<div id="newform">` of my webpage after submit a form. All I know is the code `window.location.href`, but it will redirect the entire page to the thank you page, here is my code:

```js
<script src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" > 
</script> 
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // References:
    var $form = $('#myForm');
    var $conf = $('#myConf');
    var $subm = $('#mySubmit');
    var $impt = $form.find(':input').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden');
    // Submit function:
    $form.submit(function() {
      $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
        // On success, clear all inputs;
        $impt.val('').attr('value', '').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
        // Write a confirmation message:
        $conf.html("Form submitted!!");
        // Disable the submit button:
        $subm.prop('disabled', true);
      }, 'json');
      return false;
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="newform">
    <form id="myForm" action="the script from Google">
      Your name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="your name" style="width:200px"><br> Your phone:<br>
      <input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="you phone" style="width:200px"><br> Your email:<br>
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="your email" style="width:200px"><br> Message:
      <br>
      <input type="textbox" name="message" placeholder="your message" style="width:200px"><br>
      <input type="submit" id="mySubmit" value="submit" onclick="window.location.href = 'https://www.xul.fr/ajax/anotherpage.html';">
    </form>
    <p><span id="myConf">Submit</span></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

anyone knows how to embed the "thankyou.html" (or anotherpage.html as seen from the above example) inside the division `<div id="newform">` after submitting a form?

Comment: what you can do is create an iframe and give it path to your thankyou.html and add that iframe into ```<div id="newform">``` and that iframe will render your thankyou.html page. (you can see simple documentation about iframe here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp)

Comment: I think another alternative would be adding the thankyou.html's HTML content inside the <div> from the very beginning, but setting its display property to none. When the user submits the form successfully, change the display style from none to block.

Answer (score 1):

Add this above the `}, 'json');` line:

```
$('#newform').append('<iframe src="/thankyou.html" name="frame1" id="frame1"></iframe>');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, i have added. The new iframe will appear below the form after submittion. It is possible to replace the entire form (inside <div id="newform">) with the thankyou.html after submit?

Comment: There are many ways. You can: 1) Replace the line I wrote with this: `$('body').append('<iframe src="/thankyou.html" name="frame1" id="frame1"></iframe>');` and 2) Add this line above it: `$('#newform'').hide();`.

Comment: Or you can use jQuery's replaceWith method. `$('#myForm').replaceWith('Your thankyou.html content');` You can read more from [jQuery's doc](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

Comment: Yes that is better. I forgot about `replaceWith`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all the friends here, the code replaceWith really works for me, here is the answer to my question:

```
$('#myForm').replaceWith('<iframe src="https://www.example.com/thankyou.html" name="thankyouframe" id="thankyouframe"></iframe>');
```